# Is it right to wrapp all img tag in figure tag?

Tags: html, figure

I am new to html5. I want to convert my site template from html4 to html5.

My question is : Is it right to wrapp all img tag in figure tag?

Comment: Not only is right, it's semantically right as well.

Comment: for all images ???

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure What `<img>` do you have? Logos? Frivolous `<img>` with no meaning? Since you haven't described any of your images or provided any code, I assume that your `<img>` have meaning and purpose.

Comment: Some images are between article body, for example photos of a celebration, some are news thumbnails, some are just small icons.

Comment: Everything but the small icons since they probably lose meaning if it stands alone.